# Store dynamically created text box values in an javascript array in an order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed dynamically created text boxes by clicking a `button` using AJAX. I have three text box IDs such as `morning`, `noon` and `night`. I just want to store these values in an array like `[morning, noon, night][morning, noon, night]...`

I have tried, but it stored like `[morning, morning, noon, noon, night, night]`. I can't understand how to separate as I mentioned above.

Please help me to solve my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    var modess = [
      $("input[id='morning[]']").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
        console.log(morning);
      }).get(),

      $("input[id='noon[]']").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
        console.log(noon);
      }).get(),

      $("input[id='night[]']").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
        console.log(night);
      }).get(),
    ]

    alert(modess);

    const medic = [...morning, ...noon, ...night];
    console.log(medic);
    var medical = JSON.stringify(medic);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="medical">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Medicine Name</th>
      <th>Morning</th>
      <th>Noon</th>
      <th>Night</th>
      <th>charge</th>
      <th> <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> + </button> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="rows"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page  You should avoid non-web standard compliant code.  Rather than using an attribute selector to get around the uniqueness expectations of ids, use classes instead.

Comment: **ID MUST BE UNIQUE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're grouping by input, not by row in the table.

Also note that you appears to be using the same `id` on multiple elements, which is invalid. They have to be unique. Use a common class on them all instead. Then you can use `map()` to select the values from those fields like this:

```
let modess = $('#rows tr').map(function() {
  let $tr = $(this);
  return [
    $tr.find('.morning').val(),
    $tr.find('.noon').val(),
    $tr.find('.night').val(),
  ];
});
```